# Помогите разобратся с удалением статей с БД

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, фреймворк, обработка-ошибок

Вот мой код, и он удаляет самую нижнюю статью вместо той, которая была выбрана для удаления.

```
form class="" action="" method="post">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>Номер</th><th>Название</th>
        </tr>
        <?php
         $posts = R::findAll('news' , 'ORDER BY id DESC ');
        foreach ($posts as $post) : ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $post['id'];
            $rowid=$post['id'];; ?></td><td><?php echo $post['name']; ?></td><td><button type="submit" name="delete">Удалить</button></td>

        </tr>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </table>
    <?php if (isset($_POST['delete'])) {
        $del = R::load('news',$rowid);
        R::trash($del);
        echo "Запись №".$rowid."была удалена!";
    } ?>
</form>
```

Comment: А как он знать будет, что удалять? Вы сабмитете одну и ту же форму абсолютно одинаковой кнопкой.

Answer (score 1):

Вам необходимо дополнительно передать id статьи которую вы хотите удалить. Например так: `?act=delete&id_article={ваш_ид}` потом где то в коде сделать проверку

```
if (isset($_GET['act']) && $_GET['act'] == 'delete') {
    $id_article = (int)$_GET['id_article'];

    $del = R::load('news',$id_article);
    R::trash($del);
    echo "Запись №".$id_article."была удалена!";
}
```

Comment: Извиняюсь,не совсем понимаю куда мне вставить `?act=delete&id_article={ваш_ид}`я же использую кнопку а не ссылку.Я знаю как использовать такое токо в ссылках))